# How to check if a number contains a certain digit

Tags: python

I am making a program that does various things to an inputted int, but want it to do a different action if one of the digits is 9. I have searched around but can't find any way of doing this that fits, here is my code so far:

```
Num = int(input("Enter a large number: "))
if Num  # does not contain 9
   Num2 = Num + 10
   print("If I added 10 to your number it would be:", Num2) 
   print("The new number times 2 would be", Num2 * 2)
   count = 0
   number = Num
   if (number.valueof(x).contains("9")):
       print("No 9s plz")
   else: 
       while (number > 9):
           number = number // 10
           count = count + 1
           for i in range(1, count + 1):
               Num = Num + 1 * (10**i)
               i = i+1
           print("adding one to every digit on your first number would be:", Num + 1)
else:
   print("Sorry we dont do 9s")
```

Comment: You mean you want to detect in the decimal representation of the number, whether one of the digits is 9?

Comment: To get a string containing the decimal representation of a number `x`, use `str(x)`; to determine whether a string `s` contains any character `c` (like for example, a digit), use `c in s`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think Oli was looking to check if any of his digits in the "number" variable had a "9" which is what i dealt with in my code below

Comment: @mkrieger1 True if that was what Oli was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
Num = int(input("Enter a large number: "))
if Num!=9: #does not contain 9
    Num2 = Num+10 
    print("If I added 10 to your number it would be:" , Num2) 
    print("The new number times 2 would be " , Num2*2) 
    count = 0; number = Num; 
    set1=set(str(number))
    if "9" in set1: 
        print("No 9s plz") 
    else: 
        while (number > 9): 
            number = number//10 
            count = count + 1 
            for i in range(1,count+1): 
                Num = Num+1*(10**i) 
                i = i+1 
                print("adding one to every digit on your first number would be: " , Num + 1)
else:
    print("Sorry we dont do 9s")
```